# Netbeans Swing GUI Builder persistently using features of wrong Java version (like diamond operator)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gui-builder

In the project properties, I have set "Source/Binary format" to JDK 5. (Erraneously, I had 6 before, but we need to use 5 in my project.)

However, when designing a UI panel, the created code each time again contains features that need a higher Java version (like the diamond operator `<>`, and things like `JComboBox<String>()` ).

So when compiling, I get:

> error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
>           jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

I have even edited all the .form files, where it says `<Form version="1.5" maxVersion="1.5" type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JPanelFormInfo">`
instead of `maxVersion="1.7"` which I found there.

But it still keeps creating code containing the diamond operator, even for new forms that I create from scratch!
This is driving me crazy - any ideas what I need to do to Netbeans to accept my Java 1.5 setting?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the project before executing the java form?

Comment: What netbeans version do you use?